# Jupyter stopped working in VScodium after changing from bash to zsh

Tags: python, ubuntu, conda, zsh, vscodium

[SOLVED]
@wjandrea raised the possibility that it could be a bug in the most recent version of vscodium (1.80.0). I reverted back to 1.79.2 and everything works. It was just a confusing coincidence that the day vscodium was updated was the day  I decided to mess with my shell language.

Today I decided to switch from bash to zsh. I'm running Ubuntu 22.04 and have several miniconda3 environments that I use in VScodium.

I installed zsh using oh-my-zsh. Afterwards, I ran

`~/miniconda3/bin/conda init zsh`

and it executed successfully.

Then I added the following to .zshrc

```
PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:${PATH}
export PATH
```

(I don't know if this was necessary, since now those paths are duplicated in PATH. But a lot of guides told me to, so I'm keeping it until I figure out the current issue)

Now VScode doesn't connect to the kernel (I think).

When I try to run cells the interactive window says *Connecting to myenv (Python 3.9.16)...*. Then it DOESN'T change to *Connected to...* (or whatever it usually says when it succeeds to connect, I forget now because it isn't happening), and the code doesn't run.

At the bottom right corner of the window it says `3.9.16('myenv':conda)`, which I thought meant it connected. However, if i keep trying to run cells the extension host crashes.

I thought that maybe the conda environment or VScodium needed to be installed with zsh to work. So  I reinstalled both and nothing changed.

I don't how to fix it.

Does it have to do with $PYTHONPATH (which is currently empty) ?

Does it have to do with the extension host?

Does it have to do with .zshrc or .profile?

EDIT: I switched back to bash with `chsh -s bin/bash` and it still doesn't work. So I'm in trouble now.

EDIT: VScode is connecting to the kernel (both with zsh and bash). But the jupyter extension doesn't work (both with zsh and bash). Everything works when I disable the jupyter extension. So is it some PYTHONPATH it needs? or does it need to be installed in some special way?

[image: here's a screenshot of the upper right. I think this means it is connected to the Kernel. But it doesn't leave the "Connecting to mpet" status, and it doesn't run the cell. Instead the extension host terminates unexpectedly and restarts.]

Any help is appreciated

Thank you

Comment: Thank you. I made a formatting mistake in the post. It's fixed now.

Comment: This is probably a bug, [one that I reported actually](https://github.com/VSCodium/vscodium/issues/1549). But I'm using 20.04 and wasn't able to reproduce the issue on a 22.04 virtual machine, hmm...

Comment: *"At the bottom right corner of the window it says `3.9.16('myenv':conda)`, which I thought meant it connected."* -- No, that's just the Python environment. The IPython kernel info is shown in the top right of the Jupyter interactive window. And when you say *"VScode is connecting to the kernel"*, you're referring to the bottom right, right?

Comment: Ok. I was referring to the bottom right. Now that I check, the top right indicates that the kernel connected. When I try again several times, until the extension host complains about crashing too many times, it just stops connecting to the kernel. And no environments show up when I click it (it now says "Select Kernel"). I attached an image

Comment: WOHO!! @wjandrea thanks! reverted back to vscodium 1.79.2 and everything works now. Huge relief.

Comment: Rather than answering the question in the question body, give the answer as a proper answer and accept it.

Comment: _since now those paths are duplicated in PATH_ : If you put a `typeset -aU path` somewhere in your ~/.zshrc, zsh will automatically keep the PATH clean by removing duplicate entries.

Answer (score 0):

@wjandrea raised the possibility that it could be a bug in the most recent version of vscodium (1.80.0). I reverted back to 1.79.2 and everything works. It was just a confusing coincidence that the day vscodium was updated was the day I decided to mess with my shell language.